# Django "for" loop by date

Tags: python, html, django

I'm doing blog app. I did:

```
        {% for entry in entry.all %}
                <div class="timelinestamp">
                  ...
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
        {% endfor %}
```

and almost everything works fine. I changed one Entry in my admin panel (The very first Entry...). Since then the order of my post has changed... Can anyone explain me why ? Or tell how to using loop render all Entries sorted by date ?

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    pub_date = models.DateField(null=False)
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The pub_date field is NOT primary key in my DB! I'm using Django 2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> If a query doesn’t have an ordering specified, results are returned from the database in an unspecified order. A particular ordering is guaranteed only when ordering by a set of fields that uniquely identify each object in the results. For example, if a name field isn’t unique, ordering by it won’t guarantee objects with the same name always appear in the same order.

It looks like you want to order by `pub_date`? Use [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#ordering):

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have created model definition without the `ordering` meta option items in the database are not enforced any ordering, everytime when you do `Model.objects.all()` it will give you items without any order. If you want to queries to be in specific order you can:

- Add `ordering` option to Meta options to model definition - which would require
  database migrations
- Modify your query to enforce ordering like `Model.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')` - also pass the query as context object to template like:
- views.py -

  `entries_by_pub_date = Model.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
  context['entries_by_pub_date'] = entries_by_pub_date`
- template
- `{% for entry in entries_by_pub_date %}
  ...
  {% enfor %}`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you haven't defined a sort order for your `Entry` model. This means that you will process those entries in a non-defined order.
To order your entries you could [set a default sort order](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) on `Entry`:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    pub_date = models.DateField(null=False)
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pub_date',)
```

Or, if that's not what you're looking for, you could [order your queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) in your view:

```
Entry.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
```